# How to display the maximize button in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

We only see Close window option in SharePoint 2013 in Edit, New and View Dialog forms. I need a generic solution to display the Maximize option to all the lists and Document Libraries as in SP 2010.

Please let me know how to enable the maximize button at a time to all the lists and libraries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there is any setting at list or library level to add such maximize button on forms.

Comment: Is there no possibility of adding the Maximize button through Visual Studio 2013 also?