# How to Add maximize button to the OOB forms in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

In SharePoint, when we edit, view or Add an item in lists or libraries we observe that we do not find maximize button in SharePoint 2013. How to I add the maximize button to all the lists and libraries form as we see in SharePoint 2010. I need a generic answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the maximize button in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258138/how-to-display-the-maximize-button-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, find the **SP.UI.Dialog.js** in (**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS**).

Open the file using Notepad, and then replace the code below

```
if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($p0.allowMaximize)) {
    this.$f_0 = false;
}
```

with

```
if (SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($p0.allowMaximize)) {
    this.$f_0 = true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Comment: Changing OOTB files in Layouts is never a good idea